# can not receive a message (broadcast recceiver ) through this code

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

am not getting a message through my app  - help me out i dont know what changes i have to make in this code , tell me should i make it to default(so it will give me a message) or something else do in my code - i do receive a message but not from this app

```
    public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage
                            .getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum
                            + "; message: " + message);

                    // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "
                            + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.smsmanager"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? If so what is that. Try to update with Logs. And make sure you registered BroasCastReceiver before you invoke it

Comment: And the manifest? (Permissions, receiver declaration)

Comment: Have you checked the value of bundle? is it correct?

Comment: no , am not getting any error , when ever i recieved a message , i do but frm the default messenger app , not my app ..

Comment: am using these permisson 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

Comment: @kesh ,sry i dont understand the , which value of bundle  ,

Comment: final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); in this line are you getting proper value for bundle?

Comment: @Kesh1234 yeah , am getting proper value , other wise i wont receive a proper message through default message app ..

Comment: Update the question and post your Manifest. We need to know where you register this Receiver

Comment: @SamiEl-Tamawy i updated the question and added manifest too

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan where r you registering this receiver?

Comment: @mustafasevgi Thanku so much its working ,

Comment: @SamiEl-Tamawy thanks- after registering the user , now am getting the msg

Comment: You are welcome @ArslanAliAwan :) Happy coding. Then you need to accept the below answer. He is telling you different ways of registering the receiver

Comment: @ArslanAliAwan please can you set correct answer.

Comment: @mustafasevgi i did post correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should add this code

```
<receiver android:name=".yourService" android:exported="true" > 
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

in application tag in Manifest

### or

or you must register your InComingservice in activity class.

For example

```
private InComingSMSReceiver inComingSMSReceiver = new InComingSMSReceiver();
@Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      registerReceiver(inComingSMSReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      unregisterReceiver(inComingSMSReceiver);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is correct answer , MainAtivity.java class was fine but i did make changes in manifest as u people helped me. and its working perfectly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.smsmanager"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".IncomingSms"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action             android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```